# using jquery to addclass when an anchor is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

having trouble with this.  Any help would be appreciated.
I'm trying to add the "slide" class to the left-menu div by using the Id "lm"
doesn't seem to be working for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {});

$("#toggle", ).click(function() {
  $("#lm").addClass("slide");
});
```

```css
  .left-menu {
  height: 55%;
  width: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slide {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-20, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  transform: translate(-51em, 0);
  -webkit-transition: 10s;
  -moz-transition: 10s;
  -o-transition: 10s;
  transition: 10s;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="text-vertical-center apple-effect">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">[sv]</a> </div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="left-menu" id="lm" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: remove the comma from $("#toggle",).click(function(){

Comment: You need to remove the comma from this `$("#toggle",)`

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong, put the click FUNCTION in the `$(document).ready()`, and also there is a comma(,) exist in your script at this line `$("#toggle",).click()`. Remove it.

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
       $("#lm").addClass("slide");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .Your jquery code has syntax error & Not with proper format 
Change as like this ,

**Why ?**

1. You should add the click function inside the  `$(document).ready(function() {//click function})` not with outside , And its not closing properly `})`
2. Also css `slide` class not closing properly `}`
3. `$("#toggle,")` its a invalid selector .so remove the `,` in `$("#toggle,")`

> **Note** Don't forget to add jquery library link

***Working Example***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#toggle").click(function() {
$("#lm").addClass("slide");
});
})
```

```css
.left-menu {
  height: 55%;
  width: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slide {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-20, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  transform: translate(-51em, 0);
  -webkit-transition: 10s;
  -moz-transition: 10s;
  -o-transition: 10s;
  transition: 10s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="text-vertical-center apple-effect">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">[sv]sxx</a> </div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="left-menu" id="lm" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: See my snippet its working .check the jquery library link in your html .Copy and paste my code in your html

Comment: thanks!the script works when i add it to html. i wonder why it doesn't work while in my .js flie?

Comment: See my answer I was added the reason `why?` your code not working

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that comma and check the below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#lm").addClass("slide");
  });
})
```

```css
.left-menu {
  height: 55%;
  width: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slide {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-20, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-20em, 0);
  transform: translate(-51em, 0);
  -webkit-transition: 10s;
  -moz-transition: 10s;
  -o-transition: 10s;
  transition: 10s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="text-vertical-center apple-effect">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">[sv]sxx</a> </div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="left-menu" id="lm" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click event inside document.ready() function.
And remove ',' after #toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#toggle").click(function(){
   $("#lm").addClass("slide");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using jquery click function which is going to be deprecated soon, please use

```
$("#toggle").on('click', function(){
   $("#lm").addClass("slide");
});
```